# ziparchive text files in c#

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I have a folder full of text files. I want to zip each one individually. If there are First.txt and Second.txt in the folder C:\Temp\raw
I want to zip First.txt as First.zip and move it to C:\Temp\Done and Second.txt zipped as Second.zip and move it to C:\Temp\Done. This is the code I have

```
    -- SourcePath = C:\Temp\raw tempPath = C:\temp\Done in app.config
     public static DirectoryInfo sourcePath = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourcePath"].ToString());
public static string tempPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempPath"].ToString();
     var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath.ToString(), "*.txt").OrderBy(f => f);
            string zipfilename = "";
            try
            {
                foreach (var fPath in files)
                {
                    string fileNameNoPath = Path.GetFileName(fPath);
                    string destFile = Path.Combine(tempPath, fileNameNoPath);
                    System.IO.File.Move(fPath, destFile);
                    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempPath, tempPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
```

I am getting errors. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Temp\Done' is denied
I do have access to C:\temp\folder and I am running as admin
Can someone guide me
Thanks
MR

Comment: Have you checked if the user that initiates the console app has access to the file directory?

Comment: you need to run as adminitrator.

Comment: Use Path.GetTempParh()

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't know what is Path.GetTempParh()

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(). Google it and use that as the path to the user's temp folder

Comment: Which line is throwing? Also, shouldn't `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempPath, tempPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);` be outside `for`  loop?

Comment: The second parameter or ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`` is the name of the ZIP file to be created. But you pass the temp directory name instead.